# Error on Processing when making an Ecosystem

Tags: java, error-handling, processing

I was doing an ecosystem on Processing when I couldn't make my animal reach the fruit, at first I was trying to make the animal find the food and then reach it, but it didn't work out as the animal was randomly walking the screen, so on my second try, I did something similar to gravitational attraction and made the fruit attract the animal, but I ended up with this error, "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" can anyone try to find the source of this problem?

This is the first page:

```
Animal[] animal = new Animal[1];

Predator predator;

Fruit[] fruit = new Fruit[2];


void setup() {

  size(1536, 864);


  for(int i = 0; i < animal.length; i++) {

    animal[i] = new Animal();

  }

  predator = new Predator();

  for(int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {

    fruit[i] = new Fruit();

  }

}


void draw() {

  background(60);

  fill(255);

  grid();



  for(int i = 0; i < animal.length; i++) {

    animal[i].display();

    animal[i].update();

    animal[i].checkEdge();

  }  


  for(int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {   

    PVector seek = fruit[i].attractAnimal(animal[i]);

    animal[i].gatherFood(seek);


    fruit[i].display();

  }

}



void grid() {

  strokeWeight(3);

  stroke(65);

  for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

    line(70 * i, 0, 70 * i, height);

  }

  for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

    line(0, 70 * i, width, 70 * i);

  }

}
```

This is the Animal class:

```
class Animal {

  PVector pos;

  PVector vel;

  PVector acc;

  float mass;


Animal() {

    pos = new PVector(random(0, width), random(0, height));

    vel = new PVector(0, 0);

    acc = new PVector(0, 0);

    mass = random(5, 10);

  }


  void update() {

    pos.add(vel);

    vel.add(acc);

    acc.mult(0);

  }



  void checkEdge() {

    if(pos.x >= width || pos.x <= 0) {

      vel.x = -vel.x;

    }

    if(pos.y >= height || pos.y <= 0) {

      vel.y = -vel.y;

    }

  }  



  void gatherFood(PVector will) {

    PVector w = PVector.div(will, mass);

    acc.add(w);

  }



  void display() {

    fill(255 , 150);

    stroke(100);

    strokeWeight(5);

    ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, mass * 5, mass * 5);

  }

}
```

This is the fruit class:

```
class Fruit {

  PVector pos;


  Fruit() {

    pos = new PVector(random(0, width), random(0, height));

  }



  void display() {

    fill(0, 185, 0);

    stroke(0, 100, 0);

    strokeWeight(3);

    ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, 15, 15); 

  }



  PVector attractAnimal(Animal animal) {

    PVector dir = PVector.sub(pos, animal.pos);

    dir.normalize();

    float walk = 10 / animal.mass;

    dir.mult(walk);

    return dir;

  }


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Not a duplicate. He understands why, but can't figure out where it's coming from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {   

    PVector seek = fruit[i].attractAnimal(animal[i]);
    // this line and the previous for i = 1
    animal[i].gatherFood(seek);


    fruit[i].display();

  }
```

You have 2 fruits and one animal. When you are accessing `animal[i]` for the I = 1, which is the second animal, you are out of the available index of the array, resulting to this exception.

Comment: oh, I see, but that's really bad written code, right now each fruit is "chosen" for each animal, what I wanted to do is have more fruits than animals and the animals choose the closest fruit and then move on... I think I need to study more to accomplish this lol, anyway, thanks for answering so fast :)